# Can M-LVDS be used as bus protocol?

Tags: communication, can, bus, network-interface

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-1177.pdf

In the document, it states that CAN is robust but M-LVDS is low power alternative of that. However, I couldn't be sure if it can be really an alternative to CAN for some applications. Is there anyone who uses it as a bus interface(i.e for industrial applications)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be used for buses because it is designed to be a multipoint electrical interface.

For example it is used to implement the physical interface of LXI WTB bus.